# Group by is not working properly in mysql select statement

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a table I use to store messages for a conversation. This is my query:

```
  SELECT
    a.id,
    a.`from member_id`,
    a.`to member_id`,
    IF(a.`from member_id`={$targetID}, a.`to member_id`, a.`from member_id`) as other_id,
    a.text,
    MAX(a.`date sent`) as `date sent`,
    a.to_read,
    m.`first name`,
    m.`last name`,
    m.avatar_name,
    m.avatar_status
  FROM message a
  JOIN members m on IF(a.`from member_id`={$targetID}, a.`to member_id`, a.`from member_id`) = m.id
  WHERE (a.`from member_id`={$targetID} OR a.`to member_id`={$targetID}) AND a.active=1
  GROUP BY IF(a.`from member_id`={$targetID}, a.`to member_id`, a.`from member_id`)
  ORDER BY `date sent` DESC
```

The message table is like:

```
id               int(11)           id of the message    
from member_id   int(11)           id of the person the message was sent from
to member_id     int(11)           id of the person the message was sent to 
date sent        datetime          date of when it was sent 
active           tinyint(1)        if the message is deleted    
text             longtext      the text of the message
from_read        tinyint(1)        boolean to know if the person who sent it read it 
to_read          tinyint(1)            boolean to know if the person who it got sent to read it
```

This select statement is used to show the list of conversations you currently have. For example, it is exactly the activity you get when you click the texting icon on an android smartphone, where you see a list of conversations, and each one has the most recent message that was exchanged between you and another person.

So what I am doing in the select statement is get the messages where your id is in the `to` or `from`, then group it so that the row being used is the most recent message exchanged between you and the other person.

The issue is that, when a person sends a text to them self, the most recent text doesn't show up.

Does anyone know whats the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To quote your question:

> So what I am doing in the select statement is get the messages where
>   your id is in the to or from, then group it so that the row being used
>   is the most recent message exchanged between you and the other person.

This may be what you want to do.  It is not what the query is doing.  The `group by` clause is:

```
GROUP BY IF(a.`from member_id`={$targetID}, a.`to member_id`, a.`from member_id`)
```

When it encounters multiple rows that meet the condition, it chooses an *arbitrary* value for reach field from those rows.  The `order by` has nothing to do with choosing the most recent message, even if that is what you want.

To get the most recent message between two senders, try this:

```
select least(`from member_id`, `to member_id`) as id1,
       greatest(`from member_id`, `to member_id`) as id2,
       max(id) as theid
from messages m
group by least(`from member_id`, `to member_id`),
       greatest(`from member_id`, `to member_id`);
```

This will provide the list of the most recent message ids (assuming they are assigned in increasing order).  You can join this into your query to get the most recent message.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your query. The message table has rows that are messages from multiple conversations. I am trying to get specific rows from this table. Each of the row that I want, should be the most recent message exchanged between you and the other person. Also the order of the rows returned should be ordered so the most recent conversation is on top. Also when the group by condition satisfies more than one row, I try to make it so that it picks the most recent row because I put `MAX(a.date sent) as date sent` on top, so doesn't that make the group by pick the most recent one?

Comment: @omega . . . The answer to your question is "no".  If you want the most recent one, you need to calculate it and join it in.